# In Selenium, how to handle InvalidSelectorException while log in website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to log in website with selenium. This is the code that I made.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://abcde.com")

assert "xxx" in driver.title
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox")
user.clear()
user.send_keys("username")

pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$passwordTextbox")
pwd.clear()
pwd.send_keys("mypassword")
pwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

When I run this code, **InvalidSelectorException** has occurred.

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
>     (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64)

I've attached png file for your convenience.
[image]
This is the page source in the website.

```
<input name="ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$userNameTextbox" type="text" value="Username" id="ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox" OnClick="UsernameBehaviour(&quot;click&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox&quot;, &quot;Username&quot;);" OnFocus="UsernameBehaviour(&quot;focus&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox&quot;, &quot;Username&quot;);" OnBlur="UsernameBehaviour(&quot;blur&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox&quot;, &quot;Username&quot;);" />            
<input name="ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$passwordTextbox" type="password" id="ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_passwordTextbox" OnBlur="PasswordBehaviour(&quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_passwordTextbox&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox&quot;, 1);" style="display:none" />
<input name="ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$tempPasswordTextbox" type="text" value="Password" id="ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox" OnClick="PasswordBehaviour(&quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_passwordTextbox&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox&quot;, 2);" OnFocus="PasswordBehaviour(&quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_passwordTextbox&quot;, &quot;ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox&quot;, 2);" />
```

I have attached png file for the convenience.
[image]

As you can see, there are two input box related password. When I click password input tag, javascript seems to do something. But I'm not sure.

I would like to know the reason and solution.

Thanks for your time.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using CSS selector incorrectly. It needs to have an element tied to it, but you are trying to find using an attribute value.

In order for it to work you need to change your CSS selector to this.

**Solution 1.**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox']")
```

**Solution 2**

As the elements have name attribute, you can use  "find_element_by_name".

```
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$tempPasswordTextbox")
```

Comment: Hi, Madis. Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry to say that username input box works well. but the error has occurred because of password input box. I would like to know about this.

Comment: @YuiryKozlenko Hmm. Then could it be the issue that the password field is "hidden".  style="display:none". This might cause the issues. Switch it to the correct input field. 
pwd = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("
ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$tempPasswordTextbox")

Comment: @YuiryKozlenko Currently you are trying to send Keys to the hidden password field, but why not send them to the one which is displayed? driver.find_element_by_css_selector(" ctl00$MasterHeaderPlaceHolder$ctl00$tempPasswordTextbox")

Comment: Hmm, let me see. I think the issue might be that the following symbol $ isn't handled by Selenium well, which gives the exception.  Could you try driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id='ctl00_MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox']")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148705/discussion-between-madis-kangro-and-yuiry-kozlenko).

Comment: Thank you again for your help.