# selenium with python : InvalidSelectorException

Tags: python, selenium

Using this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.booking.com')  
browser.find_element_by_id('ss').send_keys("Galway")
browser.find_element_by_class_name('xp__dates-inner').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('data-date=2019-05-14').click()
```

I'm attempting to select the element `data-date="2019-05-14"`

But receive exception :

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "data-date=2019-05-14" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: 'data-date=2019-05-14' is not a valid selector: "data-date=2019-05-14"
```

Have I set the id of the selector correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Selenium, how to handle InvalidSelectorException while log in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990388/in-selenium-how-to-handle-invalidselectorexception-while-log-in-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.However when use any `attribute` with css selector you have to use parathesis `[attribute="value"]` excluding id and class.
However you can use id and class without parenthesis.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-date="2019-05-14"]').click()
```